# Change color of a string - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm making a command line based game in Haskell and need to make a string a certain color. I'm fairly new to Haskell but I made a game last night. I basically need to change the "Welcome to the Haskell Guessing Game" non-colored string to a different colored string if possible.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.5.0/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html

Comment: Linking to projects like that is basically SPAM. Try to keep all the relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot color a string. A string is just a sequence of characters. You can however tell a terminal to print a string in certain colors, if the terminal supports it.

So you should use some library which can deal with terminal stuff like that. The [`System.Console.ANSI`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.6.2.3/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html) module provides ANSI terminal support for Windows and ANSI terminal software running on a UNIX-like operating system, which is likely to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me. You can run this code [here](https://replit.com/@alexhkurz/ColouredHaskellOutput#Main.hs).

```hs
-- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html for the colours
main = do
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[0mdefault"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[30mblack"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[31mred"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[32mgreen"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[33myellow"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[34mblue"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[35mmagenta"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[36mcyan"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[37mwhite"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[90mblack"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[91mred"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[92mgreen"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[93myellow"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[94mblue"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[95mmagenta"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[96mcyan"
  putStrLn $ "\ESC[97mwhite"
```

Comment: You can use putStrLn $ "\ESC[32mgreen\ESC[0m" in order to restore the default color.