# How do I use System.Console.ANSI to wrap a String in escape sequences for getting it colored in the terminal?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ansi-escape, terminal-emulator, ansi-colors

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220186/5825294) I've learned about [`System.Console.ANSI`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.6.2.3/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html), and at that doc page I read of the "strawberry" flavour functions, of which I read that

> has a `String` type and just consists of an escape code which can be added to any other bit of text before being output.

which feels just what I want in pure code, a way to take a `String` and wrap it somehow in escape sequences, so that when that `String` finds its way in the `IO` monad and will printed in the terminal, it gets printed, say, in red.

How can I use the aforementioned module for this?

Clicking on the [`Example.hs`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/feuerbach/ansi-terminal/master/System/Console/ANSI/Example.hs) link gives a 404.

Comment: Likely the example was moved to https://github.com/UnkindPartition/ansi-terminal/blob/master/ansi-terminal/app/Example.hs ?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, I guess that's the one, but I only see `IO ()` entities there... I don't see any `String -> String` function :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "strawberry" functions are the ones that end in the `Code` suffix.

Note that they don't **transform** `String` values.  They simply **produce** `String` values that, when output to an ANSI terminal, perform the desired action (changing the color, moving the cursor, whatever).  So, for example, you can define a pure `String` value by concatenating codes and plain text:

```
redHelloWorld :: String
redHelloWorld
  = setSGRCode [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
  ++ "hello world"
  ++ setSGRCode [Reset]
```

and write it to the console in `main` or some other `IO` function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn redHelloWorld
```

A full sample program:

```
import System.Console.ANSI

redHelloWorld :: String
redHelloWorld
  = setSGRCode [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
  ++ "hello world"
  ++ setSGRCode [Reset]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn redHelloWorld
```